# Golden Cheetah - Speed and cadence values keep dropping every few seconds

Tags: training, indoor

I'm trying to use Golden Cheetah to record my indoor riding data this winter, and I'm having an issue trying to get the sensors to read consistent data.  Every few seconds it will show the correct value for speed and cadence, but then drop down to a lower value for, usually about 1/2 to 1/3 of the actual value. Heart rate data which is also read on the same ANT+ USB stick.

When I try using IPBike on my Android tablet it seems to be able to read the data consistently and gives nice smooth readings.

I've tried using a USB extension cable to put the USB ANT+ stick closer to the sensor, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

The behaviour is exactly the same both on my Windows machine and my Linux machine.

I have a new battery in the speed/cadence sensor

Both the ant+ stick and the speed/cadence sensor are unbranded ones that I got off AliExpress a few years ago.  I suppose this could be the issue and it's just bad hardware, but I would like to try to resolve it without buying new hardware if possible.  It seems like the ant+ stick reads the heartrate data just fine, and the speed/cadence are sending the data appropriately as other apps can read the data. I think it just comes down to how Golden Cheetah is interpreting the data it receives.

Also, I tried it with Zwift, and the sensor data seems to be reading consistently, so it seems like an issue with Golden Cheetah rather than some kind of connection issue since Zwift uses the same Ant+ stick for reading the data.

Comment: There is a [Golden Cheetah user group](https://groups.google.com/g/golden-cheetah-users) that might put your question in front of a more relevant audience.

Comment: The main GoldenCheetah developer is usually extremely helpful. Maybe he can help you (though it could be hard since he probably doesn’t have access to the same hardware).

Comment: @AdamRice I posted to the Golden cheetah user group. I'll update here if I find a solution.